# How do I SELECT data based on pairs of columns (themselves the result of a SELECT)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following table structure:

```
TABLE session
    int entity_id
    int user_id
    int status

TABLE entity_user
    int entity_id
    int user_id
    int target
```

The `session` table logs interactions by different users on different entities. The `entity_user` table specifies which users have access to each entity. Significantly, each user can have access to more than one entity.

I want to select (entity, user) pairs from the `session` table based on some criteria, eg. a particular status. Having retrieved those pairs, I want to look up the corresponding target in the `entity_user` table for each pair.

Is there a way to do this cleanly in SQL, ideally with a single query?

My solution so far was to select the pairs, do some offline text processing to concatenate them (with a separator) and then use that text. Thus:

```
SELECT entity_id, user_id FROM session WHERE status = 100;
-- Returns (101, 234), (204, 157), etc.
-- Post-process this result using # as a separator
SELECT entity_id, user_id, target FROM entity_user
  WHERE CONCAT(user_id, '#', entity_id) IN ( '101#234', '204#157', ...)
```

This works, but I feel like there should be a *pure* way to do this in SQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: @e4c5 Not yet, but I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with a combination of subquery and join.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT entity_id, user_id FROM session WHERE status = 100 ) as s
LEFT JOIN entity_user ON s.entity_id = entity_user.entity_id and s.user_id = entity_user.user_id
```

Comment: This solution completed very quickly compared to the other which was very slow. So this is my pick.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

You can use pairs for `IN` in MySQL:

```
SELECT entity_id, user_id, target
FROM entity_user
WHERE (user_id, entity_id) IN (SELECT user_id, entity_id FROM session WHERE status = 100);
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `session(session, entity_id, user_id)`.  You can also use a `join`:

```
SELECT eu.entity_id, eu.user_id, eu.target
FROM entity_user eu JOIN
     session s
     USING (user_id, entity_id)
WHERE s.status = 100;
```

For this, indexes on `session(status, user_id, entity_id)` and `entity_user(user_id, entity_id)` would be useful.

Comment: I gave this a try but the query did not complete after several minutes so I stopped it. For reference, the inner query takes about 40-50 seconds when run stand-alone, while my earlier CONCAT-based query takes about 10 seconds. I kind of expected the pure solution to take an equivalent amount of time. Any thoughts?

Comment: @dave . . . I noticed that the two columns were in different orders for the `in` tuple and the subquery.  That might fix your problem.  I also updated the question with index suggestions.

Comment: thanks for following up. I checked and I had the tuple in the same order in both cases, so that's not the issue. You're probably on the right track with indexing. I don't think I'll be able to add an index into production for such a specialised case.